# What is the equivalent of EEDATA from BASIC and EWrite in C language?(How to use the EEPROM with xc8 compiler?)

Tags: c, pic, basic, xc8

I am having a very hard time figuring out how I can use:

```
EEDATA = 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03 ;
```

and turn that into C code. From what I can understand, it's a way of allocating memory in BASIC, but I really do not know. If anyone out there could help I would much appreciate it.

It was programmed using PROTON. I believe it's got to do with EEPROM used for PIC hardware.

Comment: BASIC or VBA? Don't be fooled by the word "Basic" in VBA, it's really quite different from old BASIC. Furthermore, if you're not using Visual Basic for ***Applications*** (the A in VBA) but plain Visual Basic, use the either the `vb6` tag for the older version or `vb.net` tag for the newer.

Comment: Which basic on which platform are you talking about? `EEDATA = 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03 ;` doesn't look like any BASIC stuff I've ever seen. You need to provide more context.

Comment: Which C compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using XC8 on MPLAB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you want to do. But I guess you want to preload your EEPROM with the XC8 compiler. Use the following code:

```
__EEPROM_DATA(0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00);
```

Be sure to always use a block by 8 values.

To write and read the EEPROM you can easily use the library functions:

```
include xc.h


void eeprom_write(unsigned char addr, unsigned char value);
unsigned char eeprom_read(unsigned char addr);
```

Comment: I see so I would add _EEPROM_DATA in the area near to declaring variables?

Would I need to use a header so I can use eeprom_write(...); What do these two functions do?

Comment: When I copied your code _EEPROM_DATA.... I got an error on MPLAB X saying: Unable to resolve identifier. Does it mean I need to include a header file with the eeprom?

Comment: you had to add xc.h. And please remember the two underscores. __EEPROM... and not _EEPROM..

Comment: Thank you it works now. I wil try the read and write sooner this week

Comment: How can I do that Mike?

Comment: Where it says ewrite:

if (GESTURE == 10) {
            //EWrite 4, [DURATION_BUZ] ;
            //DelayMS (2) ;
        }

Would I write: void eeprom_write(unsigned char 0x00, unsigned char value);

Comment: I did it. Hope it helped you :)